# spark join change equalTo function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I have two datasets and I would like to merge the tables if the element of a column contains the element of the other.
How can I do?

```
val df = df1.join(df2, 
    df1.col("Complete Name").equalTo(df2.col("Name")))
```

Into

```
val df = df1.join(df2, 
    df1.col("Complete Name").ifContain(df2.col("Name")))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Dataset<Row> d1 = datasetFromJsonStrings(listOf("{\n" +
    "  \"key\": \"name\",\n" +
    "  \"origin\": \"left\"\n" +
"}"));

Dataset<Row> d2 = datasetFromJsonStrings(listOf("{\n" +
    "  \"key\": \"complete name\",\n" +
    "  \"origin\": \"right\"\n" +
"}"));

// [name,left,complete name,right]
List<Row> rows = d1.join(d2, d2.col("key").contains(d1.col("key"))).collectAsList();
```

**Note:** I did it in Java out of convenience because my entire codebase is in Java, not Scala.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like this

```
{
df1.join(df2, df1.col("Complete Name").ifContain(df2.col("Name")), "left_anti)
.union(df2.join(df1, df1.col("Complete Name").ifContain(df2.col("Name")), "left_anti))
}
```

Didn't test it though.